Topology on $C^0(X,Y)$ to have a continuous action
Let $G$-acts on $X,Y$ (on the left) continuously. I.e., there are some topologies on $X,Y,G$. Now consider the set of all continuous functions $C(X,Y)$.
First, we could define either of the following action, $g.f:=$ $f\circ g^{-1}$ or $g\circ f\circ g^{-1}$ or $g\circ f$.
First, is any of the three actions more natural to consider?
Second, how would we define a topology on $C(X,Y)$ to make $G$ act on it continuously with respect to the action mentioned above respectively? Should the topology be different or the same for the three different actions? I personally think the compact-open topology might be involved.
